# Call an Obj-C multi-input method in the Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to call an Objective-C multi-input method in Swift, for instance:

```
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didSendDataWithTag:(long)tag
{
NSLog(@"Did send with tag");
}
```

How could I call this method? By using "udpSocketdidSendDataWithTag"? It doesn't work.

Comment: Read the Swift books provided by Apple. it's in there.

Answer (score 1):

It's swift would likely be something similar to this:

```
func udpSocket(_ sock:GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didSendDataWithTag tag: long) {
    // use parameters 'sock' and 'tag'
}
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
udpSocket(socket, didSendDatawithTag:tag)
```

There are also many resources now on Objective-C and Swift interoperability.  A quick search of google or [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_25) will reveal solid answers.

---

[Edit]

As user [Thomas Killan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/thomas-kilian) mentioned, don't forget to setup the Interoperability by using a Bridging Header.  Apple has great documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Don't forget to include the header in the <proj>-Bridging-Header.h